# Upload a file to Dropbox from Azure webjob

Tags: c#, azure, dropbox, webjob

I have been looking all over the place but I'm having a hard time finding out how to upload a file to Dropbox from an Azure webjob.  Is this even possible?  I will be creating an excel file and a text document in my webjob that i will need to place in a certain Dropbox account (which i have access) folder.

Comment: Can't you consume Dropbox API in your Webjob to upload a file?

Comment: I believe so, yes.  Can i just use the api to upload files to an account and not actually put them on a physical drive?

Comment: You would need to provide some context before I could answer that :). Please update your question and tell from where you're getting the data files in your webjob. Essentially more details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement, I assumed that you could follow the possible approaches below to achieve your purpose.

**1.Call Dropbox API in your WebJob**

You could leverage [Dropbox.NET](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet) which is a portable Class Library for you to easily integrate Dropbox into your WebJob.

**2. ApiHub extension for Azure WebJob**

You could leverage [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub/) which is a pre-release version for you to integrate Dropbox with WebJob. For more details, you could refer to [Azure WebJobs extensions sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/dev/src/ExtensionsSample).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (if you don't want to deal with DropBox API) you can build a logic app being triggered for example by HTTP request from your web job as DropBox connector exists:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-dropbox